# My code works perfectly on C Online Compiler but not from my computer

Tags: c, compiler-errors

So, **I'm new to C** and I have this homework from college that I need to simulate a hangman game, at first I'd made the entire code in an online compiler and it worked all good, but then I decided to download a local compiler and somehow the same code doesn't work :(

First problem: **it doesn't recognize the first letter as "a", but recognizes all the others in sequence**

Sec problem: **when I type 0 to try to guess the entire word, whatever I type, it just ends the program and closes the window**

I'm just reproducing the way my teacher did in class, so it is all basic 'cause we're starting to learn

So here goes the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define n 10

int main() {
    char s[n], p, p_complete[n], asterisk[n];
    int i, counter, p_loop, rights;
    
    
    rights = 0;
    counter = 1;
    
    
    strcpy(s, "algoritmo");
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        asterisk[i] = '*';
    };
    
    
    
    while(p != '0' && counter < n-1) {
        printf("\n\nWord: %s", asterisk);
        printf("\n\nType a letter: ");
        scanf("\n\n%s", &p);
        
        for (p_loop = 0; p_loop < n-1; p_loop++) {
          if (s[p_loop] == p) {
            asterisk[p_loop] = p;
            rights++;
          };
        };
        
        counter++;
    };
    
    if (p == '0') {
        printf("\nType the entire word: ");
        scanf("%s", &p_complete); 
    };
        
    if (strcmp(p_complete, s) == 0 || rights == n - 1) {
        printf("\nCongratulations, you won!");
    } else {
        printf("\nOh no, you lose!");
    };
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("\n\n%s", &p);` hmmm... not good.... `p` is a char. It's not a char-array

Comment: Before you print `asterisk`, you need to terminate it with `\0`. Next, `p` is a `char`, don't use `%s` in `scanf` to read values for it - use `%c`.

Comment: I hope this is not how your teacher did....

Comment: And what's with the `};`s?

Comment: Your handling of `rights` is also wrong. You can get incorrect values for it they way you are currently doing things.

Comment: So, I had one single class of C so most of what I wrote was intuitive, the %c for char my teacher didn't introduced yet so thanks. The }; was how I thought it worked, thank you for correcting me. But for the asterisk part, I coudn't understand, can you give me an example how to fit it in the code?

Comment: Oops. I thought I had, but had a typo in my earlier comment. What I intended to type was:   You forgot to null terminate asterisk. After the loop where you fill most of it with '*', you need to add a null terminator .  `asterisk[n-1] = '\0';`.   C style strings need a null ('\0`) character to mark the end of string. This is implicitly provided for string literals ("algoritmo")

Comment: There is some basic problem with `n`. It seems you use it for two things. 1) It sets the size of your char-arrays like `s[n]` and 2) it is used as the limit for how many times the player may guess doing `&& counter < n-1`. That seems like two completely different things so you need two different defines

Comment: Now assume a user keeps giving the input **A** over and over again. The `while` will then end when `counter < n-1` becomes true. Then `p == '0'` will be false so the user will **not** be asked to input the entire word. Next step is: `strcmp(p_complete, s)`. Now my question for you is: **What is the value of** `p_complete` in this case?

Comment: "... the %c for char my teacher didn't introduced yet ..." Sure!? If your teacher never told about %c but only told about %s, the program would be completely different as everything should be based on string (word) input.... The posted code clearly indicates that input is expected as chars

Comment: OT: `#define n 10` hmmm... 1) It's common to use upper case for defines 2) Defines should have meaningful names! It could be `#define CHAR_ARR_SIZE 10`

Comment: On first while loop p is unitialized.

Comment: "If your teacher never told about %c but only told about %s, the program would be completely different as everything should be based on string (word) input..." Yeah... She really only introduced the %s and the %d, maybe she forgot to tell us about the %c because she was coding with vectors and then asked us to do this homework as a challenge. But really thank you for all the information, I'll take notes for the next time :), C turns out to be very complicated as we have begun with pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sec problem: **when I type 0 to try to guess the entire word, whatever I type, it just ends the program and closes the window**

It's because of this line:

```
scanf("%s", &p_complete);
```

`p_complete` is a `char` array, which will decay to a pointer to its first element. So, passing `&p_complete` is actually passing the address of the pointer to the first element. What you should be doing is

```
scanf("%s", p_complete);
```

---

Some other issues with your code:

1. Avoid `#define`s as much as you can. Better use `const` as an alternative.
2. `strcpy()` is not not necessary in your case. Moreover, it is error-prone and you should use it with caution.
3. Declare variables near where you use them.
4. `while (p != '0' ...)`: You are using an uninitialized variable (`p`), and this is undefined behaviour.
5. `scanf("\n\n%s", &p);` is wrong: `p` is a `char`, not a `char*`. So `%c` format must be used.
6. Why are you writing `};`? `;` is not necessary here, and it means an empty statement after `}`.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const size_t size = 10; // size_t: the proper type for sizes
    char s[size], p, p_complete[size], asterisk[size];
    int counter = 1, rights = 0;
    
    snprintf(s, size, "%s", "algoritmo");
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        asterisk[i] = '*';
    }
    asterisk[size-1] = '\0';

    while(p != '0' && counter < size - 1) {
        printf("\n\nWord: %s", asterisk);
        printf("\n\nType a letter: ");
        scanf(" %c", &p);
        
        for (size_t p_loop = 0; p_loop < size - 1; p_loop++) {
            if (s[p_loop] == p) {
                asterisk[p_loop] = p;
                rights++;
            }
        }
        
        counter++;
    }
    
    if (p == '0') {
        printf("\nType the entire word: ");
        scanf(" %s", p_complete); 
    }
        
    if (strcmp(p_complete, s) == 0 || rights == size - 1) {
        printf("\nCongratulations, you won!");
    } else {
        printf("\nOh no, you lose!");
    }
}
```